# What is a safe way to pass the `this` pointer to another function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have defined a class that holds a reference to a list of static functions which are defined 
outside of the class. These functions each take a pointer to that particular instance of the class as a argument.

I'm passing the `this` pointer to the functions. But that doesn't seem right to me.

Is there a better way?

The code below is a simplified version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A
{
    public:
       typedef void (*action_func)(A*);
       typedef std::map<int, action_func> func_map;

       A(func_map the_map)
          :m_map(the_map)
       {}

       void execute_action(int action_id)
       {
          auto it = m_map.find(action_id);
          if(it != m_map.end())
          {
             auto cmd = it->second;
             cmd(this);
          }
       }

    private:
       func_map&  m_map;
};


static void function_1(A* ptrToA)
{
    std::cout << "This is function_1\n";
}

static void function_2(A* ptrToA)
{
    std::cout << "This is function_2\n";
}


static func_map functions =
{
    {1, function_1},
    {2, function_2}
};


int main()
{
   A obj(functions);
   obj.execute_action(1);
   obj.execute_action(2);
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the above is this:

```
This is function_1
This is function_2
```

Comment: This constructor         A(func_map the_map)
       :m_map(the_map)
       {} invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Vlad thank you - I didn't realise. Is there a better way to instantiate the reference to the map?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is correct, because the constructor is using pass-by-value. The parameter is a temporary that will be destroyed at the end of the constructor, and keeping a reference to it is bad.

Comment: Did you mean for your member variable to be a *copy* of the map rather than a reference?

Comment: @Mark Ransom - thanks. No I didn't want to take a copy of the map. I thought I could just create a reference to it.

Comment: @BithikaMookherjee if you want the `m_map` member to be a reference, then the constructor needs to take a reference as input: `A(func_map &the_map) : m_map(the_map) {}`, then you just have to make sure the `func_map` that is passed in lives longer than the `A` object that references it.  Which in your example, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When storing references and pointers to things outside the class it is important to reason about their lifetimes. Generally, the thing being referenced should outlive the thing that references it.

In your particular case, `static func_map functions;` has static [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration), that is it is created before `main()` starts and is destroyed after `main()` ends.

So you can safely use it inside `A obj`, which lives within the scope of `main()`:

```
int main()
{
   A obj(functions);
   . . .
}
```

However, the constructor of `A` isn't just storing it - it stores a reference to its temporary copy instead:

```
   A(func_map the_map)
      :m_map(the_map)
   {}
   func_map&  m_map;
```

What's worse, the temporary copy lives only until the end of the full-expression, i.e. until the end of `A obj(functions);`. So if you use it after that you will be accessing a dangling reference (undefined behavior).

To fix that, change it to a pass by-reference:

```
   A(func_map& the_map)
      :m_map(the_map)
   {}
   func_map&  m_map;
```

Now there's no issue.

> I'm passing the `this` pointer to the functions. But that doesn't seem right to me.

The same lifetime reasoning applies - if the thing where you pass `this` into doesn't use it for longer than `this` is alive, then technically there is no issue. In your case the function calls are synchronous, so by definition `this` is alive during each function call.

Whether or not it's "right" from a design perspective is impossible to say from the provided example. There could be better solutions, but there are also design patterns (e.g. Strategy Pattern) that are based on passing a reference to self around. So in the end it's a design choice.